# Why does node keeps the process active after forked Node process finished executing the script

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, jestjs

I've setup a very basic example for `jest-workers` demonstrated [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-worker):

**parent.js**

```
import Worker from 'jest-worker';

async function main() {
  const worker = new Worker(require.resolve('./Worker'));
  const result = await worker.hello('Alice'); // "Hello, Alice"
}

main();
```

**worker.js**

```
export function hello(param) {
  return 'Hello, ' + param;
}
```

**Whenever I run the code with `node index` the process keeps hanging. Why is that the case?**

Under the hood `jest-worker` uses `[child_process.fork][2]` function provided by Node.